# how to pass data from string type to integer to make line chart using mpandroidchart

Tags: java, android, graph, linegraph

I am making an app in android studio with java in which I want to make a line graph with the mpchart android library. The data that I want to represent in my graph is obtained by reading a sqlite database. The idea is that the x axis shows the time and date while the axis and the amount of data. The problem is that the method to insert the values ​​into the dataset with which it is graphed only accepts numeric values ​​and the data that I read from my database are integers and strings, so My question is how to convert the date and time string to an integer so that the graph works for me?
my code:

lineGraphClass:

```
public class lineGraphClass {
    int count;
    String date;

    public String getDate() {

        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {

        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

conexionsqlitehelper.class:query database:

```
public List<lineGraphClass> dataDebatebyGroupDate(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT count(arguments.id_arguments),arguments.date_arguments FROM arguments WHERE arguments.arguments_summary_debate_relation =? ";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        List<lineGraphClass> data = new ArrayList<lineGraphClass>();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                lineGraphClass fill_data = new lineGraphClass();
                fill_data.setCount(cursor.getInt(0));
                fill_data.setDate(cursor.getString(1));
                data.add(fill_data);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        return data;
    }
```

lineChart.class:class that will draw the line graph

```
public class lineChart extends Fragment {
    public String name,title;
    List<lineGraphClass> data;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_line_chart, container, false);
        LineChart linechart = view.findViewById(R.id.linechart);
        LineDataSet linedataset = new LineDataSet(fillDataset(),"");
        ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(linedataset);
        LineData linedata = new LineData(dataSets);
        linechart.setData(linedata);
        linechart.invalidate();
        return view;
    }
    private ArrayList<Entry> fillDataset() {
        ConexionSQliteHelper conn = new ConexionSQliteHelper(getContext(), "lala", null, 40);
        name = getArguments().getString("name");
        title = getArguments().getString("title");
        int id = conn.requestId(name);
        int id_text_discuss = conn.requestIdDiscuss(id, title);
        data = conn.dataDebatebyGroupDate(id_text_discuss);
        ArrayList<Entry> datavalues = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            datavalues.add(new Entry(data.get(i).getDate(), data.get(i).getCount()));
        }
        return datavalues;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not very familiar with the LineChart stuff you are using but from what I understood, you want the dates to be arranged in ascending/descending order on the X-axis. If that is correct, I think a proportional conversion of the `Date` string to something like seconds completely should do it.